# Why is this animation not uniform?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a circle that expands and contracts, but there is a glitch at about 10px - 20px.  Look carefully and you will see it "twitch".

It's as if the the circle has some alloted space and then "breaks" out of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/nj2u9bhy/4/

```
$A.Class.create('test',{
    Name: 'Animator',
    E: {
        timer: '#timer'
    },
    init: function(){
        this.animate();
    },
    animate: function(){
        var s = this.E.timer.style;
        var step = 2;
        var state = 'up';
        $A.setInterval(function(){
            $A.log(step);
            s.height = s.width = step + 'px';
            s.borderRadius = step/2 + 'px';
            if(state === 'up') {
                step += 2;
            }
            if(state === 'down') {
                step -= 2;
            }
            if(step === 2) {
                state = 'up';
            }
            if(step === 42){
                state = 'down';
            }
        }, 200);
    } 
});
```

I tried explicitly giving it space here:

https://jsfiddle.net/nj2u9bhy/5/

but same effect.

Comment: It's happening at 14px.

Comment: Because it is inline-block. Change to block and that change of path goes away

Comment: I won't trade an upvote for you accepting my answer, so I deleted my answer and upvoted @LGSon's answer (which is better anyway) instead.

Comment: @cadegalt0 We don't trade points here at SO, if users like your question (and behavior) they likely upvote, and same goes for an answer. Accepting an answer is for future users to know which solution you preferred, as in many case there is more than 1 answer, which match other users need.

Answer (score 3):

That is because it is an inline block element which vertical aligns to bottom so give it vertical align top solve the issue, or change it to a block element.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/nj2u9bhy/7/)

```
#timer{
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

And it can be easily done using CSS animation which will give a smoother transition (note that CSS animations are not supported in IE 9 and earlier)

```css
#timer{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: zoom 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes zoom {
  0% {width: 0; height: 0;}
  50% {width: 32px; height: 32px;}
  100% {width: 0; height: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the solution involving a CSS3 animation supports fewer browsers.

Comment: @LukeTaylor Yes, though today this solution has +90% browser coverage

Comment: Very true. Just thought that your answer should note that it's supported in fewer browsers, in case the poster needs to support old browsers.

Comment: @LukeTaylor Since all major browser support it (+1 version down), we don't write that, or else we would need to do that on almost all answers.

Comment: You don't think it's even worth noting? What if the poster has a specific requirement to support IE9? I know they didn't mention it, but the excuse that it would take a lot of effort isn't a good one for not even mentioning it.

Comment: @LukeTaylor Nope, not in this case, I gave a solution for script, and the CSS was a bonus ... and users that knows to support older browser normally knows this, and if not, they ask questions here why their animation doesn't work in IE9 :)